# Looking for a perl-based CMS that is easy to extend

Tags: perl, cms

This is for a non-profit group, which means shared-hosting, which generally means no mod_perl.  FastCGI is ok.

I'm looking for a CMS that can accept perl-based plugins which can be melded seamlessly in with the authentication/authorisation of the CMS (which probably means "CMS written in perl").  This is because we have some data that I'd rather *not* modify in wiki format every time it changes.  I'd rather be able to put it in a database (I'm using CSV right now, but can migrate to SQLite or MySQL later) and control the layout independently from the data.  I'm not sure there'd be a plugin that already does what I want to do, which is why I think I need to be able to write my own.  And I already know perl, not PHP, since I use perl at $work.  And since this is for non-profit, picking up PHP is probably a bit much right now.

News, wiki, forum are all important, in that order.  Calendar and photos are nice-to-have, but I can live without them.  The ability to add plugins is also important.

Hopefully there is something out there that has most of this plus an active, open community that continues to add to it.  I'm just not that good at some aspects of this project (mostly HTML, CSS, JS) and would like to be able to build on something rather than start anew.

Comment: it's an almost exact match for pinax [http://pinaxproject.com/], except for the Perl part (pinax is Python, built on Django)

Comment: http://catalystframework.org http://mojolicious.org/

Comment: @Brad Gilbert: those are nice looking frameworks, but I'm more hoping for something where a layout and lots of HTML is already done, and I can more or less deploy it, after adding a page or two (plugin or something so I can take advantage of the pre-built authentication system).  Neither Catalyst nor Mojolicious seem to have news, wiki, or forums already.

Answer (score 3):

[Movable Type](http://www.movabletype.org/) or [Melody](http://openmelody.org/)?

Answer (score 1):

[Cyclone3](http://www.cyclone3.org) is very interesting. Partial list of Perl's CMS is available at "Applications" article in perl5 wiki.